# Excel VBA to move data from a table in one sheet to a table in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with two tabs. The first tab is titled "StagingArea" (table name on sheet is _StagingArea) which has data grouped by module. What I'm trying to do is dynamically move data from the table in the "StagingArea" sheet (_StagingArea) to the table in the "Module1" sheet (_Module1). So, if a new row gets added for module 'Module1' in "StagingArea" I need that to then be moved to "Module1" sheet. So far, I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = Sheets("Staging Area").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets("Staging Area").Cells(i, "A").Value = "Module1" Then
Sheets("Staging Area").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Module1").Range("_Module1").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The problem I'm running into is that it is looping through the rows for "Module1" but only inserting the last row into the table on sheet "Module1."

I also need to then delete the rows from "StagingArea" sheet that were copied/moved over to the "Module1" sheet. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Maybe it is always copying the data into the same row of `_Module1`. Check where `Range("_Module1").End(xlUp).Offset(1)` goes. And your second problem, there are two ways to achieve it. 1. Delete it by `Range(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete` directly, but you have to scan through the range backward, that is, from `LastRow` to `2`. 2. Dim a `Range Object`, `Union` those rows you would like to be deleted, then delete them when all jobs are done at once. This is better when you have hundreds of thousands of data rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move operation is achieved by Copy followed by Delete. There is no inbuilt move functionality in VBA to achieve this. Hence, I have modified your code a little. Hope, it helps.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i as Long, LastRow as Long
    Dim rng as Range

    LastRow = Sheets("Staging Area").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Staging Area").Cells(i, "A").Value = "Module1" Then
            Sheets("Staging Area").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Module1").Range("_Module1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = Sheets("Staging Area").Cells(i, "A")
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, Sheets("Staging Area").Cells(i, "A"))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As I commented in OP's thread, I doubt that `Range("_Module1").End(xlUp).Offset(1)` will return the second row of `_Module1` every time you copy a data. I'm not sure what table looks like in OP's workbook, however I suggest editing it to `Range("_Module1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)`

Comment: Totally makes sense.